# I want to create a unique customer ID in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unique

Hello guys i want to create a unique id with prefix in it and then want to enter it in database, the customer id field needed to be primary as i tried many things but all got failed as mysql is not letting me make that field primary, 
i tried to create customer id like this 
`$pre="brbn_";
$v=0001;
id=$pre.$v;`

Here the mysql query come and after this query.

Comment: you can use random no or time with prefix like `brbn_`.time()

Comment: Can you not store the prefix and unique id in separate columns?

Comment: if i will use unique id then how will i search the user again and the unique is also not my solution....

Comment: for making unique id you could use `uniqid(md5(microtime()))`. Also try to separate unique id and primary key

Comment: Insert the record but allowing MySQL to generate the `id`, and then get back that id.  For example; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html.  If you need to prefix that identity value, store that prefix as a separate column, and then combine the two on demand (in a view, a calculated column, your client, where-ever).

Comment: i am not getting it as i am new to this all can u describe me properly ?

Comment: @epicwebsol - Follow the link.  It shows an example where by MySQL creates the unique identifier when the record is being inserted, then also shows you how to get that unique identifier back to your application.  There is no need for you to create your own unique identifier.  Then for your "prefix" requirement, just have another column in the data that you insert called (for example) `id_prefix`, you can then concatenate the `id_prefix` and `id` columns whenever you like.  But the *real* identifying column will be `id` and it will be managed by MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use your string in a unique field in the databse but not as primary because your id isn't numeric. mysql uses primary to may autoincrement or something like this.
you could create a primary id and unique user id and stor it in the database.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
           `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
           `uid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `uid` (`uid`)
) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `uid`) VALUES (1, 'brbn_0001'),(2, 'brbn_0002');
```

of course you should make field ID autoincrement :)

since you have created your db and just want to increment your $v you have to select from db first

```
SELECT uid FROM test DESC LIMIT 1
```

this returns the last entry... now you can use php to cut your string.
try some like

```
$var = explode("_",$result);
```

in $var[1] you have the value 1

now increment $var[1]++;

now you have to bring the number back to 4 numbers

```
$var = str_pad($var[1], 4);
```

you could do this in two rows like

```
$var = explode("_",$result);
$var = str_pad(++$var[1], 4);
```

than add your prefix and insert into your database

Comment: I tried unique too but got the error before but rite now i want to generate a customer id which will something like brbn_and some value like any no. or anything else which i may be suggested here .

Comment: here you see a test db with a id (primary) and a uid (unique), i add 2 rows each has 2 values (id,uid).... uid is varchar, that means it can contain chars like brbn_ and numbers like 1

Comment: I have created the table and databse already i need a way to generate the unique id as the way i choosed it will always going to add brbn_0001 cause $v never get changed and as the registration.php being loaded it will get the same result..

Comment: i don't know if i get this right... you have these vars and want to count up $v to e.g. 0002 because brbn_0001 already stored in your db ?

Comment: than manualy add 1 like $var = $var+1; or $var++; or $var += 1;